# iOs9 Swift spritekit,SKEmitterNode fatal error: "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value "

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, ios9, option-type, skemitternode

working on this code for few hours without success,please advice:

i am building an ios 9 spritekit game.this method:

```
func createFiringParticles(location:CGPoint, force:CGVector){

    let fireEmitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "FireParticles")

    fireEmitter!.position = location
    fireEmitter!.name = "fireEmitter"
    fireEmitter!.zPosition = 1
    fireEmitter!.targetNode = self
    fireEmitter!.numParticlesToEmit = 50

    fireEmitter!.xAcceleration = force.dx
    fireEmitter!.yAcceleration = -force.dy

    self.addChild(fireEmitter!)

}
```

gives this error:
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

the error is not initiated at first (so it works for few minutes till it crash).i tried to unwrap the SKEmitterNode with NSKeyedUnarchiver:

```
    var unWrappedFireEmitter = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FireParticles", ofType: "sks")!
    var fireEmitter = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(unWrappedFireEmitter) as! SKEmitterNode
    fireEmitter.position = location
    fireEmitter.name = "fireEmitter"
    ..........
    self.addChild(fireEmitter)
```

without any success.
**how can you unwrap SKEmitterNode? is it something in sks file?**
[image]
many thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: You are force-unwrapping (`!`). If the optional variable is `nil`, that won't magically give you a valid instance. You need to check that it is not `nil` before force-unwrapping. This is very basic stuff, I think you should read the Swift book at least: https://itunes.apple.com/jp/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11

Comment: In your particular case, `NSBundle...` might very well return `nil`: e.g., you specified the path of a non-existent file to read from.

Answer (score 1):

`NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile()` is throwing an exception because it expects a non-`nil` string (type: `String`) as the argument, and you are passing an **optional** string (i.e., type `String?`) and force unwrapping it, when it just happens to contain `nil` ("no value at all") instead of a valid value.

This seems to be happening because the earlier call to `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(_:, ofType:)` must be failing (the path can not be found among your resources. i.e, said file does not exist).

In your particular case, this code should work:

```
let optionalFireEmitter = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FireParticles", ofType: "sks")

if let unWrappedFireEmitter = optionalFireEmitter {
    // you can use your unWrappedFireEmitter, no need to append "!"
    // (it is already unwrapped)

    // (...your code here...)
}
else{
    // NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource() returned nil: Can't use.
    // Make sure the file name and extension you specified are correct
    // and that the resource file is included in your binary.
}
```

Comment: thanks,i have already tried this way but this leads to more errors (in a 1000' lines code) i need to find a way to give a non nil value to the unwrappedFireEmitter if nil.is it possible?

Comment: What errors exactly? It is a very common piece of code.

Comment: If your `pathForResource` returns `nil`, there's nothing you can do. You must fix the name or extension that you passed, and make sure your project has the specified resource.